# Unable to received notification in device notification section in android

Tags: android

This is my code to receive notification

```
public class FirebaseMessageReceiver
        extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

i am trying to received notification  from firebase console i am able to get to get call back when fire notification i am also getting title and msg code executed successfully but i am unable to see notification in notification section of device can any one please help me what i am doing mistake .

Answer (score 0):

For devices running Android O or higher, you need to create a notification channel first in order to receive notifications like this:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );

            channel.setDescription("This is Channel 1");

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
}
```

Also, you need to pass this CHANNEL_ID constant in NotificationCompact.Builder constructor like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use notification channel?
If you are using Adroid 8 or higher it's expected behavior:

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be
> assigned to a channel or it will not appear.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels

Here you can find detail tutorial how to create notification channel:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels